# how to get href value from web page using xpath

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to get href values from a web page, executed without error but not getting href value. please any one help me on this

```
url = "https://journals.sagepub.com/action/doSearch?field1=Keyword&text1=cancer&field2=AllField&text2=&Ppub=&Ppub=&AfterYear=&BeforeYear=&earlycite=on&access="

red = requests.get(url)

page_source = red.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

elms = soup.select('div.ol.li[1].article.h2.span a')

for i in elms:

   print(i.attrs['data-item-name'])
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use css selectors (not xpath)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Css selector is wrong.Your css selector should be like `div ol li article h2 span a`

```
url = "https://journals.sagepub.com/action/doSearch?field1=Keyword&text1=cancer&field2=AllField&text2=&Ppub=&Ppub=&AfterYear=&BeforeYear=&earlycite=on&access="

red = requests.get(url)
page_source = red.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
elms = soup.select('div ol li article h2 span a')

for i in elms:
   print(i['href'])
```

### Output:

```
/doi/pdf/10.2182/cjot.2012.79.1.5
/doi/full/10.1177/1073274818775360
/doi/full/10.1177/0024363918811637
/doi/full/10.2217/whe.15.57
/doi/pdf/10.1177/1077558709335536
/doi/full/10.1177/1757975914537094
/doi/full/10.1177/1073274819846603
/doi/pdf/10.1191/0748233701th098oa
/doi/pdf/10.2190/PM.40.2.d
/doi/pdf/10.1177/070674371005501203
/doi/pdf/10.1177/030089161109700213
/doi/pdf/10.1177/1721727X1100900215
/doi/pdf/10.1177/1049732310387798
/doi/full/10.1177/2051415818755626
/doi/pdf/10.1136/jms.7.4.177
/doi/pdf/10.1177/1066896909333778
/doi/full/10.4137/CIN.S5460
/doi/full/10.4137/CMO.S603
/doi/full/10.1177/0194599814551718
/doi/full/10.4137/CIN.S13788
```

Comment: Please make  sure you accept the answer if it resolved your issue.Thanks